# jQuery Mobile website is strangely magnified in Opera Mobile 10 despite 100% zoom level

Tags: opera, mobile-website, jquery-mobile

I've developed a mobile website based on jQuery Mobile. Everything works on my own Windows Mobile device with Opera Mobile 10, but a customer of mine always sees the page magnified.

I thought that he might have a zoom setting >100% in Opera Mobile, but he claims that this is definitely not the case.

The same problem also occurs on the jQuery Mobile test site ( http://jquerymobile.com/test/ ) . Here's a screenshot of the site as displayed on my customer's device:

[image]

Any idea what might be going wrong here? I was unable to reproduce this problem on my own device or in an emulator.

My customer's device is a HTC HD2  runing Windows Mobile 6.5 and Opera 10.

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: Can you post a link to your website or provide some sample code?

Comment: @James Goodwin: This is not related to my website. The same problem also occurs on the official jQuery Mobile website: http://jquerymobile.com/test/

Comment: I bet it's a version or configuration problem. Tell him to install latest opera again and see if it helps. I also noticed that JQM support site mentiones win6.5.1 not 6.5. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Adrian did you ever find a working solution to this problem?

Comment: @Blowsie: I wish I knew. Despite several follow-ups, the client that reported this problem lost interested in using the website with his Windows Mobile device entirely and did not reply to me ever since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just paste [the answer](http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/525941?t=1298393029&page=1#comment8605431) by David Storey which was made for this on [Opera Dev forums](http://dev.opera.com/forums/). It is not specifically about the 100% issue, but there might be similar issues related to the viewport tag issue, for people getting across it.

> Opera Mobile assumes that any document
>   with a mobile specific doctype, such
>   as XHTML Mobile Profile or XHTML Basic
>   are designed and optimised for mobile,
>   while documents with a regular doctype
>   are not optimised for mobile
>   generally. Thus if there is a desktop
>   doctype the overview mode is enabled,
>   which you can control with the
>   viewport meta element. If there is a
>   mobile doctype the overview mode is
>   disabled and a regular 1:1 viewport is
>   used.
>
> There were some bugs in the viewport
>   meta element support in Opera Mobile.
>   They should be fixed in the latest
>   version.

Comment: Thanks! I have to admit that does look like a very good reason why this might be broken. I'll ask my client try it when I deploy the next version of our website.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adjusting the scale?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use xhtml mobile doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
```

Comment: Not really necessary, it's acceptable to use the HTML5 doctype on mobile devices.

Comment: @James Goodwin: I think you are right, if a special doctype was necessary for mobile devices, the folks at jQM would definitely know about this.

Comment: with xthml mobile doctype opera mini/mobile will/should render it as mobile webpage and fit properly

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`. Opera seems to behave better when it's there.

If that doesn't work, please file a bug report https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/.